# non breaking phone number, content p

Tags: php

I am trying to put a non breaking phone # on a wordpress website. (123) 456-7890. This function.php from your forum works:

```
function non_breaking_hyphens($content){
  return str_replace('-', '&#8209;', $content);
}

add_filter('the_content', 'non_breaking_hyphens');`
```

I can have a non breaking phone# like this 123-456-7890.  Of note, (123)-456-7890 breaks after the closing parenthesis.

One page on the website has coupons and I can see from css that the coupon itself is content and the text in the coupon (with a phone #) is content p.  Is there a way the above function can target content p instead of content.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question, but you may be looking for the non-breaking whitespace character, `&nbsp;`.  Instead of typing a character, type `&nbsp;` and the space will never break to the next line.

Comment: Thank you for responding

Comment: Welcome.  Is that all you needed?  If so, please accept my answer.

Comment: Hi,Sorry to bother you again, Back to my original question. Is there a way the function.php I posted above can also work for the text in the Coupon  Thank You